# Store textbox data to an array and do this multiple times C# button click

Tags: c#

I have a bootstrap form where the user inputs values into three textboxes:
1. Recipient Type (To, CC, Bcc)
2. Email e.g. ab@test.com
3. Team Name e.g. Orange

When the user clicks the add button this should store the first set of values in an array. Then I want the user to be able to input values into the same text boxes and click the add button and it stores these values as a second row into the array and has the ability to continue doing this for however many recipients they need.

Once the user has added all recipients they need I will have a button to be able to view all the recipients added in a `table/gridview` format.

I have managed to get the textbox values into variables on the backend code. However, I am not able to add this to an array multiple times.

```
   protected void AddRecipient_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      RecipientType = Request.Form["recname"];
      Email = Request.Form["emailname"];
      SubTeam = Request.Form["subteamname"];


  }
```

Example:

1. Enter 'To'
2. Enter 'ab@test.com'
3. Enter 'Orange'
4. Press Add button

The array created: [To,ab@test.com, orange]

1. Enter 'Cc'
2. Enter 'dd@test.com'
3. Enter 'Red'

Array or data table: [To,ab@test.com, orange] -- Row 1
                     [Cc,dd@test.com, Red] -- Row 2

Comment: What does the `Request` class look like?

Comment: I am using request.form similar to this page: https://www.w3schools.com/asp/asp_inputforms.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplest way is to create a class called "Contents"

```
public class Contents
{
    public string RecipientType;
    public string Email;
    public string SubTeam;
}
```

Declare a global variable in code behind

```
List<Contents> Data;
```

Put the following in pageload.

```
 if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
         Data = new List<Contents>();
         Session["Data"] = Data;
    }
    else
         Data = (List<Contents>) Session["Data"];
```

In your Add Button event do this.

```
protected void AddRecipient_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        var newItem = new Contents
                      {
                         RecipientType = Request.Form["recname"],
                         Email = Request.Form["emailname"],
                         SubTeam = Request.Form["subteamname"]
                      };
        Data.Add(newItem);
        Session["Data"] = Data;
}
```

Advantage of doing this is, you can actually bind "Data" to your gridview. And then you can implement update, delete very easily.

Answer (score 0):

maybe it help you

```
private string[,] mass;
private int index = 0; 
protected void AddRecipient_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
            mass[index,0] = Request.Form["recname"];
            mass[index,1] = Request.Form["emailname"];
            mass[index,2] = Request.Form["subteamname"];
            index++;


  }
```

Answer (score 0):

According to me, instead of making the frequent call to server this should be handled on the client side.

**So steps should be**

1. User enters data
2. Press Add button This should store an object in the javascript array(E.g dataArray).
3. A table or grid should display all the entries in dataArray
4. And when finally user hits submit. that array should go to the server.